# Brand Image resizing/ Webflow

Tags: responsive-design, webflow

I’m trying to make my brand image larger at the top of the page, but Webflow is not allowing me. Anyone know how to fix this? Also does anyone know how to change the gradient colors in this template?

https://preview.webflow.com/preview/dan-the-baking-man-upgraded?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=dan-the-baking-man-upgraded&preview=d77107e0ddecb4c38fc4f9487940ab48&workflow=preview

Answer (score 0):

To increase the size of your logo to say 100x100px, try

```
.brand-image {
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

If this doesn't work, test if you need to add !important; to each of the properties.

For the colours, it looks to me that they are set in 2 places

```
body {
    background-color: var(--swatch_879f80bc);
    }
```

and

```
.background-primary-image{
    background-image: url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/6144c33b7975b17710abbbef/6144c33b7975b10e34abbc4e_Background%20Gradient.png);
}
```

Comment: Hi David, Thank you so much! I am a beginner, and am a little confused where to add this.

Comment: I don't have a Webflow account to check for sure, but according to https://university.webflow.com/lesson/custom-code-in-the-head-and-body-tags you'd go to Project Settings > Custom Code. Add them to the Head section so that they'll be applied to every page, and remember to wrap your CSS in <style> ... </style> tags